# How to skip logging uncaught exceptions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When using custom `exceptions_app` and `rescue_responses`, an application has more control of uncaught exceptions and an excessive logging from `DebugExceptions` middleware becomes noise.

As an example, the application knows how to process `ActionPolicy::Unauthorized`, renders proper page in `exceptions_app` and thus the following log is redundant:

```
FATAL -- :   
FATAL -- : ActionPolicy::Unauthorized (Not Authorized):
FATAL -- :   
FATAL -- : app/controllers/topics_suggest_controller.rb:47:in `topic_load'
```

What would be the most idiomatic way to skip logging only those exceptions listed in `rescue_responses`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some historical notes are below. As of June 25, 2021, my PR to Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42592 has been accepted and this functionality will be available in Rails <s>6.1.5</s> [7.0.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md#rails-700alpha1-september-15-2021)

---

## Approach 1

It's tempting to delete `DebugExceptions` middleware from the application's Rails stack.

`config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
```

The problem is that it is exactly the middleware that determines Rails cannot find a route and throws `ActionController::RoutingError` in such cases. Hence, if you would like to react to this exception in your `exceptions_app`, this approach is a no-go for you.

Go ahead and use this approach if it's fine for you to see HTTP status 404 and plain text response `Not found` when no route was found.

## Approach 2

Monkey patch or change `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions` in some way. In fact, there was a proposal in 2013 to change `DebugExceptions` behavior so that it skips logging exceptions registered in `rescue_responses`: [9343](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9343), there is an example code in there.

I think it's too much to overwrite the whole class, so I chose to override its [method `log_error`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb#L161) responsible for logging errors.

`lib/ext/suppress_exceptions.rb`:

```
module Ext
  module SuppressExceptions
    private

    def log_error(_request, wrapper)
      exception = wrapper.exception
      return if ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses.key? exception.class.name
      super
    end
  end
end
```

`config/initializers/error_handling.rb`:

```
require_dependency 'ext/suppress_exceptions'

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions.prepend Ext::SuppressExceptions
end
```

Comment: Your second approach is good, although I instead monkeypatched `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions#logger(request)` to log them my way.

Comment: @Lloeki good to know I'm not the only one who needs something like this. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33976), you are welcome in case you have anything to say.