# Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType ("charset=utf-8" is not a valid MIME type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since upgrading to Rails 6 we began getting these errors: `Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType ("charset=utf-8" is not a valid MIME type)`. I assume `charset=utf-8` doesn't make any sense as a MIME type, but can't rescue these errors out:

```
  rescue_from Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType, with: :raise_not_found
```

Is it possible this exception raises before even hitting our controller?

Answer (score 1):

`Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType` was added with this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35753

```
This PR adds the InvalidMimeType in the default rescue_responses from
the ExceptionWrapper and will return a 406.
```

More about `rescue_responses`: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch

Did you try with this solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475865/4414956 ? Monkey patch or remove InvalidMimeType from rescue_responses and handle it on your own.